# What is the difference between these two class instances?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There are noticeable difference between `Moped::Collection` object instances. The inspection of `Item.collection` object is as follows (with line ending added):

```
#<Moped::Collection:0x007fb381e3ed10
  @database=#<Moped::Database:0x007fb381e3fa30
    @name="production_datagatherer",
    @session=<Moped::Session
      seeds=[
        <Moped::Node resolved_address="22.22.22.22:43700">,
        <Moped::Node resolved_address="22.22.22.22:43700">
      ]
      database=production_datagatherer
    >
  >,
  @name="items"
>
```

`Item.collection` `Moped::Collection` object has following instance variables:

```
@database: Moped::Database object
@name: "items"
```

`@database` variable has the format `#<Moped::Database:0x007fb381e3fa30` while `@session` instance variable has a `Moped::Session` object but it is formatted differently.

- Is the value of `@session` not an object?
- What kind of variables does it have if they aren't instance variables (`seeds` and `database`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually much simplier.
`Moped::Session` [implements `inspect` method](https://github.com/mongoid/moped/blob/master/lib/moped/session.rb#L146)

```
def inspect
  "<#{self.class.name} seeds=#{cluster.seeds} database=#{current_database_name}>"
end
```

that's why it looks different. By default `inspect` includes instance variables as it happens with `Moped::Collection`.

`inspect` method is called on an object when it is printed with `p` method, or is returned to console. You can read about `inspect` [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Object.html#method-i-inspect)